# Solving system of inequalities with more than 3 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, several-complex-variables

How to solve system of more than 2 linear inequalities with more than 3 variables?
By graphing it requires multi-dimensional graphing and i can't find how to do this graphing.
Algebraic solution for that is not found too.

So is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: One way is [Fourier-Motzkin elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination), analogous to Gauss' elimination for linear systems of equations.

Comment: Yes, there is a solution. Please add the inequalities you have (and say what you didn't find algebraically).